# Model properties binding in android viewmodel

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I've tried some examples with viewmodels and databinding using BehaviorSubjects and other Observables. Now I have real (data class) object in Kotlin, which holds most of the state. It is basically pojo, but independent from viewmodel and has no observables.
I don't understand how can I bind this automatically to ex. TextView in android without creating external observable variables in viewmodel and some boilercode. I'd think this is something very common in mvvm pattern. Or am I missing something totally?

Comment: You should implement [binding adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)

Answer (score 0):

Using Google's `ViewModel` component you should bind your **view** to the **ViewModel** class only. And your **ViewModel** class should take care of pulling the data from somewhere (from **interactors**, for example).

In your case, you can have Observable in the **ViewModel** which will pull the data from Kotlin class you mentioned. And your **view** will get this data from ViewModel's observable directly.

If I don't understand you correctly - please provide your code with more details :)

Comment: Yes, but the data you get is for example model or data class - with properties. I'd like to do stuff with that property, for example to bind it to view.

Comment: Well, if taliing about "canonic" updating UI from the model - you can use RxBindings (if preferr Rx): https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding.  Or LiveData provided by Google in Architectural Components: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata